# Can't import keys to keyring, nothing happening

Tags: thunderbird, keyrings, pgp, openpgp, enigmail

I'm trying to use Keyring's import functionality but nothing happens - neither an error of any sort, nor any of my keys getting imported into Keyring's GUI.

I created a public/private key using `gpg` on the command line, then exported it with the public key in one file and private key in another:

```bsh
mykey.public.asc
mykey.private.asc
```

I've successfully uploaded them to `pgp.mit.edu` and `keyserver.ubuntu.com`.  But when I try to import them, either from the local files or the keyserver, nothing happens.  No error, no import.  Anyone know what might be the problem?

I'm actually doing this primarily to start using PGP in Mozilla Thunderbird email via Enigmail, in case that makes a difference.

---

```
$ sudo gpg --list-packets byron@vaurum.com.asc
:public key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1392086961, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [2048 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
:user ID packet: "Byron Gibson (Vaurum \x7c Head of Operations) <byron@vaurum.com>"
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 6C9477CDD2CEA3C9
    version 4, created 1392086961, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
    digest algo 2, begin of digest 95 81
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2014-02-11)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 03)
    hashed subpkt 11 len 5 (pref-sym-algos: 9 8 7 3 2)
    hashed subpkt 21 len 5 (pref-hash-algos: 8 2 9 10 11)
    hashed subpkt 22 len 3 (pref-zip-algos: 2 3 1)
    hashed subpkt 30 len 1 (features: 01)
    hashed subpkt 23 len 1 (key server preferences: 80)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 6C9477CDD2CEA3C9)
    data: [2047 bits]
:public sub key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1392086961, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [2048 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 6C9477CDD2CEA3C9
    version 4, created 1392086961, md5len 0, sigclass 0x18
    digest algo 2, begin of digest c9 b1
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2014-02-11)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 0C)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 6C9477CDD2CEA3C9)
    data: [2047 bits]
```

Comment: "I've successfully uploaded **them**" -- did you upload your _private_ key? I guess most keyservers will reject them anyway, but you should never send this to anybody. _How_ did you (try to) import them? Is this on the same machine you used to create the key? Then it should still be stored in GnuPG, anyway.

Comment: Oh, and what does `gpg --list-packets mykey.public.asc` output?

Comment: Thanks, by "uploaded them" I meant I uploaded multiple public keys to keyservers using the commandline `gpg --send-keys`, i'm just using a single public key for the example to simplify.

Comment: Added `gpg --list-packets` output.

Comment: The exports looks totally fine. I could also fetch your key from the SKS keyserver pool (which also contains both the MIT and Ubuntu key servers), so also uploading succeeded. What are you doing for importing/fetching the key?

Comment: Thank you.  I'm trying to import them both into Ubuntu (12.04) Keyring, and into OpenPGP/Enigmail in Mozilla Thunderbird.  With Keyring I use `File -> Import` and select the same .asc file as I used for the `gpg --list-packets` output above, but nothing happens, nothing is added.  I imagine I've got the wrong format, like maybe the private and public keys should be in the same (tried that, no luck) or something, but not sure what it is.  I also notice Keyring isn't asking for root priviledges when I do this, should it?

Comment: It should not require root privileges, your keyring is stored in `~/.gnupg`. I'm not sure if the default Ubuntu keyring is able to deal to manage your GnuPG keyring, you might want to try Seahorse. As your OpenPGP key probably already is imported on your computer, all that should happen is a message that nothing was changed.